# tinyMCE problems with removing

Tags: javascript, tinymce

well, i am using tinyMCE in a backoffice that works mostly through ajax. I have fancybox and jqueryui accordion loading the php that contains the textarea and javascript tinyMCE.init.
When i save my content, through an independent button,  and close the fancybox it was on, i can never use another fancybox or accordion , or even the same without reloading the page, because tinyMCE content comes out empty and uneditable.
I tried tinyMCE.remove(); tinyMCE.destroy(); when closing and it still happens.

So i tried a different approach, every time the user cancels or saves the content, i refresh the page. But i keep getting an alert message:

> "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.
>   (this is in firefox, i get the same message in other words in other browsers)

How can i prevent the  browser from doing this?

Thank you

Comment: If the browser wants to warn the user, you can't do much about it. I'd fix your problem instead of suppressing the symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to shut down tinymce correctly

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, editor_id);
```

and reinitialize it afterwards correctly

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, editor_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to refresh your page to have several instances of a tinyMCE object.

After you create a new textarea and set its name and id to be 'editContent', you should be able to redraw the tinyMCE boxes using the following command:

tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'editContent');

Remeber, do this only AFTER you've created the textarea's, and assigned their ids/names

Comment: thank you, but i will accept Thariama's answer, it's more complete.